"arrays to stack must be passed as a sequence" error for RBF Kernel PCA Training
I am learning Kernel PCA. When I pass the variable X into the Kernel PCS, the console popped up an error, showing that "arrays to stack must be passed as a sequence" error.
def rbf_kernel_pca(X, gamma, n_components):
    """
    RBF kernel PCA implementation.

    Parameters
    ------------
    X: {NumPy ndarray}, shape = [n_samples, n_features]
        
    gamma: float
      Tuning parameter of the RBF kernel
        
    n_components: int
      Number of principal components to return

    Returns
    ------------
     X_pc: {NumPy ndarray}, shape = [n_samples, k_features]
       Projected dataset   

    """
    # Calculate pairwise squared Euclidean distances
    # in the MxN dimensional dataset.
    sq_dists = pdist(X, 'sqeuclidean')

    # Convert pairwise distances into a square matrix.
    mat_sq_dists = squareform(sq_dists)

    # Compute the symmetric kernel matrix.
    K = exp(-gamma * mat_sq_dists)

    # Center the kernel matrix.
    N = K.shape[0]
    one_n = np.ones((N, N)) / N
    K = K - one_n.dot(K) - K.dot(one_n) + one_n.dot(K).dot(one_n)

    # Obtaining eigenpairs from the centered kernel matrix
    # scipy.linalg.eigh returns them in ascending order
    eigvals, eigvecs = eigh(K)
    eigvals, eigvecs = eigvals[::-1], eigvecs[:, ::-1]

    # Collect the top k eigenvectors (projected samples)
    X_pc = np.column_stack((eigvecs[:, i]
                            for i in range(n_components)))

    return X_pc

X, y = make_moons(n_samples=100, random_state=123)

X_kpca = rbf_kernel_pca(X, gamma=15, n_components=2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=2, figsize=(7,3))
ax[0].scatter(X_kpca[y==0, 0], X_kpca[y==0, 1], 
            color='red', marker='^', alpha=0.5)
ax[0].scatter(X_kpca[y==1, 0], X_kpca[y==1, 1],
            color='blue', marker='o', alpha=0.5)

ax[1].scatter(X_kpca[y==0, 0], np.zeros((50,1))+0.02, 
            color='red', marker='^', alpha=0.5)
ax[1].scatter(X_kpca[y==1, 0], np.zeros((50,1))-0.02,
            color='blue', marker='o', alpha=0.5)

ax[0].set_xlabel('PC1')
ax[0].set_ylabel('PC2')
ax[1].set_ylim([-1, 1])
ax[1].set_yticks([])
ax[1].set_xlabel('PC1')

plt.tight_layout()
# plt.savefig('images/05_14.png', dpi=300)
plt.show()


I am learning Kernel PCA. When I pass the variable X into the Kernel PCS, the console popped up an error, showing that "arrays to stack must be passed as a sequence" error.

Add the complete exception and the code where you initialize the parameters and call the function in which the error is occurring (Since the most likely cause is the input).
